# sIFR 3 r436 - Link doesn't work in Opera - displayed as regular text in IE

Tags: css, sifr

I got a problem with sIFR in Opera and IE.
Basically in Opera the link doesn't work, and in Internet Explorer sIFR isn't displayed at all, the text is only regular text.

It's not an issue in neither Firefox or Google Chrome.

Why is this happening and how could i prevent this from happening?
I only assign sIFR to span-classes which is wrapped inside a link or other tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey. It was a comma after the last property in between {} and IE didn't like that.
So now I have sIFR working in all browser. But not sIFR with links.
It still doesn't work with sIFR links in Opera, and now that they're displayed as sIFR the links doesn't work in IE either.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Make sure to replace the *parent* element of the link, rather than the link itself. That way the link will end up inside the Flash movie and it should work properly.

For further questions, probably best to open a new question thread.